# What is the correct javascript term for the square brackets in this context?

Tags: javascript

In the lines of the script marked 1) and 2) near the end, where I have commented, my question is about the square brackets? What is the correct javascript term for the square brackets in this context? Is the use of square brackets the same as how parenthesis works here? i.e the code inside the () parenthesis is computed first and computed values are passed out to the rest of the line to calculate the rest of the line?

Thanks Emma :)

```
 <button style="border:none; font-size: 22px;background-color:black; 
 color:white; position:fixed; top:40%; left:5%" class="w3-button w3-black w3-
 display-left" onclick="plusDivs(-1)">&#10094;</button>
 <button id="rightbutton" style="border:none; font-size: 22px;background-
 color:black; color:white;position:fixed; top:40%; right:2%" class="w3-button 
 w3-black w3-display-right" onclick="plusDivs(1)">&#10095;</button>



<script>
var slideIndex = 1;
showDivs(slideIndex);

function plusDivs(n) {
showDivs(slideIndex += n);
}

function showDivs(n) {
var i;
var x = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
if (n > x.length) {slideIndex = 1}    
if (n < 1) {slideIndex = x.length}
for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
 x[i].style.display = "none";  // 1) the square brackets here?
}
x[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block"; // 2) and the square brackets here? 
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are called **Index** or **Bracket** Property Accessors. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors

> Property accessors provide access to an object's properties by using
>   the dot notation or the bracket notation.

In Javascript you access elements of an array using the **Index**, or simply **Bracket**, notation. Which is exactly what you have in the code.

Similarly, you can access an object's properties using either the **Dot** notation:

- `myObj.property1`

Or the **Index**/**Bracket** notation:

- `myObj["property1"]`

To be exact, the **Index** terminology is more appropriate when referring to elements of an array, and the **Bracket** terminology is more appropriate when referring to properties of an object. Personally, I use the terminology interchangeably.

---

On your second question, no! Brackets `[]` are distinct from parentheses `()`. Parentheses are used for calling functions. Brackets are only used for accessing array elements or object properties.

```
function sayHello() { // Function definition. Parentheses needed. 
    return "Hello!";
} 

var result = sayHello(); // Calling a function. Parentheses needed.

var obj = { // Object definition. No parentheses.
    name: "Emma"
}

var objName1 = obj.name;  // Accessing a property using Dot notation.
var objName2 = obj["name"]; // Accessing property using Bracket notation.
```

Comment: Ok Arash, thanks a lot I understand it alot better now I think. Var x is an array of class name my slides and [i] and [slideIndex-1] are properties of X which are accessed using bracket notation? is that correct

Comment: Correct. `x` is the array. `x[i]` and `x[slideIndex-1]` are array element accessors. You can only access an array's elements using the bracket notation; so it's technically not needed to specify the `bracket` thing when referring to arrays. When referring to objects, since you have both `dot` and `bracket` notation, it makes more sense to specify it there, if and when needed.

Comment: NO, `x` is NOT an array. it is an array like object.

Comment: Yes, technically, but I think OP is a newcomer to the world of JS and I wonder if that advanced distinction is meaningful at this point. I think it's safe to regard `x` as/like an array for start. (Teacher's hat on)

Answer (score 0):

It is called [property accessor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors) with bracket notation.

> ```
> object.property     // dot notation
> object['property']  // bracket notation
> ```

You can use a stringified index, like `1` or just `1`. If the given property accessor is not a string, it gets converted to string in advanve.

You use [`document.getElementsByClassName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName):

> Returns an array-like object of all child elements which have all of the given class names. When called on the document object, the complete document is searched, including the root node. You may also call [`getElementsByClassName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getElementsByClassName) on any element; it will return only elements which are descendants of the specified root element with the given class names.

```
var x = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides"); // returns an array like object
                                                     // iterable with index and
                                                     // has a length property

for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    x[i].style.display = "none";
//   ^^^                                             // take the element at index i
}

x[slideIndex - 1].style.display = "block";
//^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^                                    // calculate an index
```

Comment: Thanks Nina, very helpful input.