# How to parse this specific json

Tags: node.js, api

I am calling a api from my node backend. It is a currency converter api.
The conversion pair is a variable. And I pass this variable with the link to the API.

So suppose var a = USD_EUR;

```
var currency = request.query.currency;
var currencyString = "USD_" + currency;
requestApi('https://free.currconv.com/api/v7/convert?q=' + currencyString + '&apiKey=APIKEY', {
  json: true
}, (err, res, body) => {
  if (err) {
    return console.log(err);
  }
  console.log(body);
});
```

I get the response as { USD_EUR: 0.90 }

So how do I use the variable to extract the value?
I can't use body.a.

Comment: show your code.

Comment: `var currency = request.query.currency;
var currencyString = "USD_" + currency;


requestApi('https://free.currconv.com/api/v7/convert?q=' + currencyString + '&apiKey=APIKEY', { json: true }, (err, res, body) => {
       
 if (err) { return console.log(err); }
        console.log(body);
      
    });`

body = { USD_EUR: 0.90 }

Comment: if `console.log(body)` outputs `{ USD_EUR: 0.90 }` then obviously to access the var you do `body.USD_EUR` (you know the key in your request so maybe use `body[currencyString]`)

Comment: You need to provide a [minimum example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

Bracket notation:

```
const myVariableName = "USD_EUR";
const conversionRate = data[myVariableName];
```

See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48354255/417866

Answer (score 0):

JSON.parse(json.replace('USD_EUR', '"USD_EUR"')).USD_EUR